# Source of Image in List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, tocloft, subcaption

I need to have my sources, for example from image files, in my list of figures.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsourcefont}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    {\leftskip\cftfigindent
     \advance\leftskip\cftfignumwidth
     \rightskip\@tocrmarg
     \figsourcefont#1\protect\par}%
  }%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
test
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test1.jpg}
        \caption{Caption1}
        \figsource{Source1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test1.jpg}
        \caption{Caption2}
        \figsource{Source2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption}
    \figsource{Source}
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Which gives me something like this:
[image: MWE]

## Problem:

I need to have the Source-Captions right under the entry, with subfigures It's totally messed up.

## What I need:

```
     List of Figures

1    Caption ............................................. 1
     URL: http://tex.stackexchange.com
     (a)    Caption1 ..................................... 2
     URL: http://tex.stackexchange.com
     (b)    Caption2 ..................................... 3
```

Hope somebody can help me,

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be perfect in a sense that figure caption is on top. But it has the main feature OP needs. `\subcaptionbox` command is used instead of `subfigure` environment. Need to compile twice.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsourcefont}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    {\leftskip\cftfigindent
     \advance\leftskip\cftfignumwidth
     \rightskip\@tocrmarg
     \figsourcefont#1\protect\par}%
  }%
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
test
\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
 {\caption{Caption}
    \figsource{Source}}
       \subcaptionbox{Caption1}
{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{test1.jpg}}
        \figsource{Source1}
\subcaptionbox{Caption2}
{ \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{test1.jpg}}
        \figsource{Source2}
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

**Update:** The OP wishes to put the caption at the bottom. So this is a workaround adding two code snippets, where `\abovecaptionskip` is modified to move the caption to bottom of the image.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figsourcefont}{\footnotesize}
\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    {\leftskip\cftfigindent
     \advance\leftskip\cftfignumwidth
     \rightskip\@tocrmarg
     \figsourcefont#1\protect\par}%
  }%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This is a test and put the caption down below the image. 

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\vspace{4cm}                            % new addon
\addtolength\abovecaptionskip{-5cm}     % new addon
\centering
 {\caption{Caption}
    \figsource{Source}}
       \subcaptionbox{Caption1}
{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{test1.jpg}}
        \figsource{Source1}
\subcaptionbox{Caption2}
{ \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{test1.jpg}}
        \figsource{Source2}
\end{figure}
\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: #Jesse
Thanks, but I want to have the \caption{Caption} under the image (bottom). So it's totally messed up. Some ideas?

Comment: @Severin -- Sorry for this late response, trying to meet your need. I just added my workaround to move the caption below. Both codes run smoothly as expected on my end .

Answer (score 1):

This short solutions is good enough for me. I don't know how it would work with subfigures. In either case @Jesse 's does much better at formatting. Maybe I'll use his in my document.

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}[2011/11/10]

\newcommand{\figsource}[1]{%
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\captionlistentry{source: #1}
}
```

In the document:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\framebox{
\includegraphics{googlecalculator}
}
\caption{The Google Calculator}
\label{fig:googlecalculator}
\figsource{Screen shot of Google calculator.}
\end{figure}
```

Produces:

[image]